# Xamarin - How to view rendered Xaml

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Our team is working on an effort to improve the accessibility of our mobile application developed with Xamarin.  One area we're having trouble tackling is Focus Path (i.e. tab order).  Research examples suggest that the focus path should naturally be top down if the layout is created correctly.  However, the examples are often simple and not real-world with respect to complex layouts and navigation (or whatever Marketing dreams up).  We have several re-usable 'controls' and templates the get injected as part of the layout like main navigation, search, etc.  The focus path, or tab order, is all over the place.

Tools that offer live preview/xaml edit only work against the opened xaml file which in many of our cases is just part of the overall xaml that makes up the screen.

Looking for a way to view 'rendered xaml' that makes a up a given screen in a xamarin mobile app.  We need to see the final xaml that includes all of the dynamic controls, templates, etc. that get mashed together.  This may help us understand what's happening to our focus path.

EDIT: we've found that forcing/setting tabindex does not help.

Is there such a tool or process?

Answer (score 0):

I was using https://www.livexaml.com/ for such a purpose.